# How does Application.dataPath work in Unity when you move the project to an iOS build

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine

My Unity game is using Application.dataPath to access the levels within the game. My question is why does Application.dataPath not work when I move my project to an iOS mobile platform.

Comment: The very first sentence for the tag [tag:Unity] is **"DO NOT USE ON QUESTIONS ABOUT THE UNITY GAME ENGINE (use: [tag:unity3d] instead)!!"**

Comment: How/Why do you say its not working?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/132753/how-do-i-read-xml-on-iphone.html

I ran into a similar problem when trying to read an xml file. I moved those files into the Resources folder and used Resources.Load("yourFile") instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be used in any platform.

In  iOS player: `<path to player app bundle>/<AppName.app>/Data`

If you're trying to read only this can be used but if you want to write you have to use

```
 Application.persistentDataPath
```

Comment: Im using Application.dataPersistentPath and it does not work when I go to iOS. Do I need to change the path at all manually for iOS? 

Also Im having trouble reading from dataPath on iOS. Which folder do I store my assets within my app bundle so that Application.dataPath works with it?

Comment: you have to use `StreamingAssets` for that purpose. It means simply you have to copy and create Data on the device manually. Just because you put data inside a folder it will not be available in the device.